# Merge 2 .bats in only one

Tags: batch-file

I have this script below:

```
@echo off & setlocal
del /f /s /q  %temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt 
del /f /s /q %temp%\DuplicateRemover.bat

echo SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo @echo off ^& setlocal >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo rem Group all file names by size >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo For /R "%%userprofile%%\Desktop\%%DATE:/=-%%" %%%%a In (*) do call set size[%%%%~Za]=%%%%size[%%%%~Za]%%%%,"%%%%~Fa" >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo rem Process groups >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=," %%%%a in ('set size[') do Call :Sub %%%%a %%%%b >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo Goto ^:Eof >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo ^:Sub >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo If "%%~3"=="" (Set "size[%%1]="^&goto :EOf) >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo processing %%* >> %temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo Keep %%2 >> %temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo Shift^&shift >> %temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo :loop >> %temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo Del  %%1 >> %temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt
echo if not "%%~2"=="" (shift^&goto :loop) >>%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt

ren "%temp%\DuplicateRemover.txt" DuplicateRemover.bat

set "spool=%systemroot%\System32\spool\PRINTERS"
set "output=%userprofile%\Desktop\%date:/=-%"

rem Timeout for loop cycle.
set "sleeptime=1"

if not exist "%output%" mkdir "%output%"


:loop

setlocal
call %temp%\DuplicateRemover.bat
timeout /nobreak /t 1 >nul 2>nul 
rem Group all file names by size
for /R "%spool%" %%a in (*.spl) do call set size[%%~Za]=%%size[%%~Za]%%,"%%~Fa"
2>nul set size[|| (
    endlocal
    >nul timeout /t %sleeptime% /nobreak
    goto :loop
)
rem Process groups
for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=," %%a in ('set size[') do call :Sub %%a %%b

endlocal
>nul timeout /t %sleeptime% /nobreak
goto :loop

exit /b 0

:Sub
setlocal

@rem If "%~3"=="" (set "size[%1]=" & exit /b 1)
echo processing %*

rem Skip 1st argument.
set "skip1="

for %%a in (%*) do (
    if not defined skip1 (
        set skip1=1
    ) else if not exist "%output%\%%~NXa" (
        rem Unique name
        echo Keep: "%%~a"
        copy "%%~a" "%output%\%%~NXa" >nul 2>nul
    ) else (
        for %%b in ("%output%\%%~NXa") do (
            for %%c in ("%%~a") do (
                if "%%~Zb" == "%%~Zc" (
                    rem Same name same size
                    call :SaveAs "%%~a" "%output%\%%~NXa"
                ) else (
                    rem Same name different size
                    call :SaveAs "%%~a" "%output%\%%~NXa"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
exit /b 0

rem Renames to output with an index number.
:SaveAs
setlocal
set "name=%~dpn2"
:NewNameLoop
set /a i+=1
if exist "%name%(%i%).spl" goto :NewNameLoop
echo Keep: "%~1" as "%name%(%i%).spl"
copy "%~1" "%name%(%i%).spl" >nul 2>nul
exit /b 0
```

When the script runs, it create another `.bat` that works together with the main script.
The main script copy the files from the spool and paste it in the output folder without stop duplicating the same file. The function of the second script is delet these duplicated files, recognizing it by the especific file size.

It's working 75% good. Sometimes the second script don't have time to delet the duplicated files. I guess is better merge these two scripts in only one. So it will work better.

Can someone help me how can i do it?

Comment: If we provide help, will you just [delete the question again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50883475)? I ask because unlike the majority of questions on here using minimal, _often fake_, example code, your request will probably take up a considerable amount of time in contrast. As you can imagine, spending that time on someone else's problem only to have it deleted on a whim, doesn't provide much motivation.

Comment: Here's five lines of example code for you to take a look at, do you think that it would completely replace `DuplicateRemover.bat`? `@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`   `CD /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%DATE:/=-%" 2>Nul||Exit /B`   `For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set size[ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A="`   `For %%A In (*) Do If Defined size[%%~zA] (Del "%%~fA") Else Set "size[%%~zA]=T"`   `EndLocal & GoTo :EOF`. I note also that you've practically replicated that structure elsewhere in your code, perhaps you can adjust that similarly if you find that it does what you need!

Comment: @Compo Firstly, i deleted the question because no one answered, you helped but in comments, so i deleted it to don't confuse other people that have the same problem and are looking for help.
In second, thanks for the help again. I replicated the sctructure bacause it was easier to me. But i already got it. Thanks again! _(And i know you also vote negative my posts...anyway like your helps...._)

Comment: Karen, I made my last response to you after 1:00 am on a Saturday morning. It is for most of us the weekend and some of us need to sleep. We are a diverse worldwide community in different timezones, so deleting your question less than four hours after your latest question edit because nobody had answered it was more than a little premature. Also just so that you and any other readers are aware, I will always inform a member that I have downvoted them and the reason why. **I have never downvoted any of your questions!**

Comment: @Compo you are true. I'll wait more now. Thanks.

Comment: @Compo hahaha sorry for that so. We are friends now, see you around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are the files of the same size?
are these in different folders?

You can do this more easily by using a [versioning system](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=52948#p52948).

```
@echo off
setlocal
set prompt=$g$s

:: This is a versioning system
:: Transfer of none or one or more parameters (folders / files)
:: A folder is created on the same level as the original folder.
:: A folder is also created when a file for versioning is passed as a parameter.
:: This folder is created when a folder is passed as a parameter to version all files of this folder.
:: Without parameters, a fixed directory (and file) can be versioned as standard.
:: A log file is maintained in the versioning folder.
:: Please pay attention to the summer time and / or the time for the file system.
:: The variable rCopyCMD is used to pass other Robocopy options.
:: The versioned file gets the current time stamp as a version feature.

set       "folderOriginal=d:\WorkingDir"

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set        "filesOriginal=*"
set        "folderVersions=.Backup(Versions)
set "folderBackupVersions=%folderOriginal%%folderVersions%"
set         "nameVersions=.(v-timeStamp)"
set      "fileLogVersions=%folderBackupVersions%\Log.(Versions).log"

:getAllParameters
if :%1 equ : goto :EndParameter
if exist %1\ (
  set       "FolderOriginal=%~1"
  set "folderBackupVersions=%~1%folderVersions%"
  set        "filesOriginal=*"
) else (
  set       "FolderOriginal=%~dp1"
  for %%i in ("%~dp1\.") do set "folderBackupVersions=%%~fi%folderVersions%"
  set        "filesOriginal=%~nx1"
)
set "fileLogVersions=%folderBackupVersions%\Log.(Versions).log"

:EndParameter

call :TAB
set "timeStamp=."

set "rCopyCmd= /njh /ts /fp /ns /nc /np /ndl /njs "

for %%F in ("%folderOriginal%\%filesOriginal%"
) do (
  set "timeStampFileName="
  set "versionTimeStamp="
  for /f "tokens=2,3delims=%TAB%" %%A in ('
    robocopy /L "%folderBackupVersions%" ".. versions Listing only..\\" ^
     "%%~nF%nameVersions:timeStamp=*%%%~xF" %rCopyCmd% ^|sort ^& ^
    robocopy /L "%%~dpF\" ".. original List only ..\\" "%%~nxF" %rCopyCmd%
  ')do ( 
    set "timeStampFileName=%%A*%%~dpB"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if /i NOT %%~dpB==!folderBackupVersions!\ if %%A gtr !versionTimeStamp! (
      call :getCurrent.timestamp
      for /f "tokens=1-3delims=*" %%S in ("%nameVersions:timeStamp=!timeStamp!%*!timeStampFileName!"
      ) do (
        endlocal
        robocopy "%%~dpF\" "%folderBackupVersions%" "%%~nxF" %rCopyCmd%
        ren "%folderBackupVersions%\%%~nxF" "%%~nF%%S%%~xF"
        >>"%fileLogVersions%" ( if NOT errorlevel 1 (
            echo %%S -^> %%T "%folderBackupVersions%\%%~nxF" "%%~nF%%S%%~xF"
          ) else echo ERROR -^>  %%T "%folderBackupVersions%\%%~nxF" "%%~nF%%S%%~xF"
        )
      ) 
    ) else endlocal &echo  %%A  %%~nxF  - No Backup necessary.
    if .==.!! endlocal
    set "versionTimeStamp=%%A"
  )
)
if NOT :%2==: shift & goto :getAllParameters
pause
exit /b

:TAB
for /f "delims= " %%T in ('robocopy /L . . /njh /njs') do set "TAB=%%T"
 rem END TAB
exit /b

:getCurrent.timestamp
 rem robocopy /L "\.. Timestamp ..\\" .
for /f "eol=D tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%T in (' robocopy /L  /njh "\|" .^|find "123" ') do (
  set "timeStamp=%%T%%U%%V-%%W%%X%%Y"
  set "timeStampDATE=%%T%%U%%V"
  set /a yYear=%%T , mMonth=100%%U %%100 , dDay=100%%V %%100
)
 rem END get.currentTimestamp
exit /b
```